# google maps + MarkerClustererPlus

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, markerclusterer

Even though markers are being groups into clusters, there are still a large of markers that arent included.

i've gone through the options but cannot figure out a way to ... increase the area in which markers get included into the cluster.

[image: markers]

Comment: Please can you post details of the options you've tried

Comment: i ended up excluding clustering.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to address this issue by increasing the gridSize option from its default 60 pixels to a higher value when instantiating your MarkerClusterer.

For example, the following instantiation code changes the grid square size of a cluster up from 60 pixels to 120 pixels:

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, { 
    gridSize: 120 
});
```

This should result in a larger cluster catchment area and fewer individual markers.

If not, I'd recommend checking that all of your markers are being included in the clustering process.

The other options you could check are the maxZoom and minimumClusterSize settings.  Whilst the following defaults for these options are intended to keenly cluster your markers, if you've adjusted these defaults you may have inadvertently reduced the degree of clustering:

- maxZoom: The maximum zoom level at which clustering is enabled or null if
  clustering is to be enabled at all zoom levels. The default value is
  null.
- minimumClusterSize: The minimum number of markers needed in a cluster before the markers are hidden and a cluster marker appears. The default value is 2.